How do I pass $event object from Angular TS file?
I have the below code which i am using to expand or collapse the elements
<div class="accordion" (click)="toggleAccordian($event, i)">

clickMenu(event: any, index: any) {
    var element = event.target;

    let elements = this.divElements.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.sub');

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].classList.remove('subactive');
    }

  }

Now i want to call clickMenu from ngInIt event. How do i pass $event

has nothing to do with the question, that's why I just write it as a comment: You shouldn't do dom modifications as you do in your clickMenu component.

You need to mock the element target, using ViewChild like so, static true is needed so that the view child is avaiable during ngOnInit hook itself!
HTML
<div class="accordion" (click)="toggleAccordian($event, i)" #accordion>

TS
@ViewChild('accordion', { static: true }) accordion!: ElementRef<any>;
...

ngOnInit() {
    this.clickMenu({target: accordion?.nativeElement} as any, 0);
}
...

...
clickMenu(event: any, index: any) {
    var element = event.target;

    let elements = this.divElements.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.sub');

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].classList.remove('subactive');
    }

}
...


Should be : this.clickMenu({target:accordion.nativeElement},0). ViewChild return an ElementRef, event.target is an HTMLElement. NOTE: also when pass from HTML a template reference variable, is an HTML Element: <div #accordion (click)="doSomething(accordion)"> pass as argument the HTML Element, not the ElementRef
